# What does normalized gamma random variable with single parameter means?

Tags: distributions, normalization

I am trying to understand a paper related to mmWave communication.

The author says (in a rephrased manner) the following

> > The transmission channel $h_l$ follows Nakagami fading with parameter $N_L$ for Line-of-Sight (LoS) communication. Therefore the channel variable $|h_l|^2$ are normalized Gamma Random Variable.

**My questions are**

i. Why is there an only a single parameter for the Nakagami fading while usually there are two parameters: Shape and the rate parameter.

ii.  What does ***Normalized*** mean in this context?

[image]

Comment: Is the density given?

Comment: No, the density is not given. Only the parameter $N_L$ is given.

Comment: Evidently, "normalized" means that a specific value is chosen for the rate parameter.  Since you don't really tell us much about the context, it looks difficult to supply anything more specific than that as an answer.

Comment: Actually, this is the whole information that is provided in the paper (unless I am missing something). I have edited the question to show the actual snap from the paper.